# phpMyAdmin will not run export

Tags: phpmyadmin

I have a database that will not export from phpMyAdmin. When I open the 'Export' tab, I get the following message:

> Warning: a form on this page has more than 2000 fields. On submission, some of the fields might be ignored, due to PHP's max_input_vars configuration.

When trying to run the quick export, nothing happens.

I have increased the max_input_vars to 3000 in all the places I can find:

- /etc/php.ini
- Added the configuration to a file in /opt/plesk/php/7.4/etc/php.d
- Added the line into 'Additional directives' in the Plesk PHP configuration

According to

```
<? phpinfo(); ?>
```

I do indeed have max_input_vars set to 3000, but still I cannot take an export of the DB in phpMyAdmin.

Strangely, I can create an export dump in Plesk. I can also use the command line.

Comment: Does your table have an extraordinary number of columns?

Comment: It doesn't. There was a table with an extraordinary number of rows, but it was removed. Issue fixed now, will update question.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the following configuration resolved this issue:

upload_max_filesize = 200M
post_max_size = 200M

I believe I now need to look into reducing the size of the DB.